# Big Objects visibility on page or reports

Tags: big-object

I would like to know any way where we can show data of Big objects in any page or in report format.

I need archival strategy where all the previous unused data needs to be added in Big objects and need to show that data so that users can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

@Arun, you can create VF page and fetch big object data there. I have fetched big object data on VF page and its quite possible. In standard reports, you can not get Big Object data.
As per your requirement, you can achieve this by fetching the data on VF page and showing the archival data to users.

Answer (score 0):

> [Big objects](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/big_objects/big_objects_get_started) support custom Salesforce Lightning and Visualforce
>   components rather than standard UI elements (home pages, detail pages,
>   list views, and so on).So you should be able to write your own custom
>   code to create a big object datable sort of thing.

[SOQL and Async SOQL:](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/big_objects/big_objects_querying) Big objects can be queried using SOQL or Async SOQL. Async SOQL uses a subset of SOQL commands. And it was designed from the ground up to handle the massive volume of data that can be kept within a big object. Because Async SOQL queries are run asynchronously, you don’t have to worry about queries timing out. Async SOQL queries run in the background, and can be run over Salesforce entity data, standard objects, custom objects, and big objects. Async SOQL is implemented via the Chatter REST API.

Also read about [Visualize Big Object data in a Lightning Component](https://johan.karlsteen.com/2017/10/15/visualise-big-object-data-in-a-lightning-component/) and [Salesforce Big Objects](https://rajvakati.com/2017/10/19/salesforce-big-objects/) this should give head start from a code standpoint.